# Programatically trigger DataBinding execution on Slider Selection

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, e4

I have a [Databinding](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdatabinding%2Fviewers%2Fpackage-summary.html) between a [Widget](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FWidget.html) ([Slider](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FSlider.html)) and a Model (int value) in my E4 Application.

If I start the Application and move the [Slider](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FSlider.html), the Model value gets updated properly, so the [Databinding](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdatabinding%2Fviewers%2Fpackage-summary.html) works. 
But if I set the [Slider](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FSlider.html) Selection via the setSelection method, the [Databinding](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdatabinding%2Fviewers%2Fpackage-summary.html) isn´t executed, so that the model value is not updated.

I tried like every other set method but nothing works. How can I change the [Slider](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FSlider.html) value from code, so that the Model is updated?

The [Databinding](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdatabinding%2Fviewers%2Fpackage-summary.html) (inside of postConstruct method from the Part):

```
protected Slider penaltyPercent;    

...

// Bind penaltyPercent  
IObservableValue observableModelPenaltyPercent = BeanProperties.value(
        Config.class, "penaltyPercent").observe(config);
IObservableValue observableWidgetPenaltyPercent = WidgetProperties
        .selection().observe(penaltyPercent);
ctx.bindValue(observableWidgetPenaltyPercent,
        observableModelPenaltyPercent);
```

The Model:

```
public class Config extends ModelObject {
    private int penaltyPercent;

    public int getPenaltyPercent() {
        return penaltyPercent;
    }

    public void setPenaltyPercent(int penaltyPercent) {
        if (penaltyPercent >= 0 && penaltyPercent <= 100) {
            firePropertyChange("penaltyPercent", this.penaltyPercent,
                this.penaltyPercent = penaltyPercent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe if I send some Event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notifying the control's listeners of a selection event might be enough:

```
Event event = new Event();
event.widget = penaltyPercent;
event.display = penaltyPercent.getDisplay();
event.type = SWT.Selection;

penaltyPercent.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, event);
```

You might need to fill in more fields in the Event.